# PCA and multiplicity of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In PCA, we construct a variance-covariance matrix and found the eigenvalues; eigenvectors are then interpreted as an axis of the ellipsoid fitted to the data.

My question is: is there any problem in finding axes of the ellipsoid when eigenvalues have multiplicity greater than 1? For example, if the largest eigenvalue occurs in double (the vector space associated has dimension=2), what will happen with the first principal axis? And will the second principal axis be constructed using also the largest eigen value?

Comment: If two eigenvalues coincide, then in the corresponding plane you have a circle. So you can choose the axes freely.

Comment: Well, I never found when browsing documents on PCA that one can choose axes freely; the first (main) pricipal axis seems always to be clearly and uniquely determined. It looks like the fact that the largest eigenvalue can be double never occurs. But why should it be so?

Comment: Well, literally the only thing I know about PCA is that it is strongly connected to the SVD of a matrix $A$ and thus to the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. If the largest eigenvalue of that matrix coming from PCA is always simple, then this can only be a result of the type of data you have.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a circle gaussian in two dimensions, PCA will capture the axis that explain the most variance, but in this case you can actually find infinite ammount of axes that have the same variance. This happens when you have eigenvalues with multiplicity greater than 1. Now you do not have an unique solution.